# Is there a way to rename object properties based on values from another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I've got an object and array of objects like this:

```js
object1 = {
  Material: ["Part ID"],
  Description: ["Desc"],
};

array1 = [
  { "Part ID": "ABC123", Desc: "sample part1" },
  { "Part ID": "DEF456", Desc: "sample part2" },
];
```

I'm looking to create a new array that uses the matching value from object1 in place of the key in array1.

The result would look like this:

```js
array2 = [
  { Material: "ABC123", Description: "sample part1" },
  { Material: "DEF456", Description: "sample part2" },
];
```

Is there an elegant way to map or loop to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you already found a non-elegant way? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: I was close, but I ultimately scrapped it as it would have been very inefficient once complete due to multiple nested loops

Comment: It's meaningful to show those who are helping you what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *pretty* simple, but the fact that you want an array of stuff in `object` makes it a bit trickier, try this:

```js
let object1 = {
  Material: ["Part ID"],
  Description: ["Desc"],
};

let array1 = [
  { "Part ID": "ABC123", Desc: "sample part1" },
  { "Part ID": "DEF456", Desc: "sample part2" },
];

let array2 = array1.map((item) => {
  // Get the keys of the current item. (E.g. ["Part ID", "Desc"])
  const keys = Object.keys(item);
  // Initialize the new object to return.
  var out = {};
  // For each key of the current array item, map it to the correct key in object1
  for (let key of keys) {
    for (let obj_key in object1) {
      if (object1[obj_key].includes(key)) {
        out[obj_key] = item[key];
      }
    }
  }
  //Return this for mapping
  return out;
});

console.log(array2);
```

Or a shorter function:

```js
let array2 = array1.map(r=>{var a,e={};for(a of Object.keys(r))for(var o in object1)object1[o].includes(a)&&(e[o]=r[a]);return e});
```

### Edit:

I totally forgot about `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`! Another way to acomplish this is like this (thanks to @trincot for this answer):

```js
array1
  .map((o) => Object.entries(object1).map(([k, v]) => [k, o[v]]))
  .map(Object.fromEntries);
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @TWiii please upvote and mark as the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let object1 = {Material: ["Part ID"], Description: ["Desc"]};
let array1 = [{"Part ID": "ABC123","Desc": "sample part1"}, {"Part ID": "DEF456","Desc": "sample part2"}];

let res = array1.map(o => Object.entries(object1).map(([k, v]) => [k, o[v]]))
                .map(Object.fromEntries);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.
This solution will run in quadratic time complexity, which is way more efficient than too many nesting and searching methods, equivalent to O(n^2).

```
let object1 = {
  "Material": ["Part ID"], 
  "Description": ["Desc"]
}

let array1 = [
  { "Part ID": "ABC123", "Desc": "sample part1" },
  { "Part ID": "DEF456", "Desc": "sample part2" }
]

let propertyNameMap = {};

Object.keys(object1).map((key) => {
  object1[key].map((name) => {
    propertyNameMap[name] = key;
  });
});


let array2 = array1.map((item) => {
  let obj = {}

  Object.keys(item).map((key) => {
    let newKey = propertyNameMap[key];
    
    obj[newKey] = item[key];
  })
  
  return obj;
})

console.log(array2);
```